# structs direct declaration in C

Tags: c, struct, initialization, assignment-operator, compound-literals

What is wrong with this code? I don't get why this isn't working.

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
} eh;

void main() {
    eh = {1, 2};
    printf("%i", eh.x);
}
```

but this works fine

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
} eh;

void main() {
    eh.x = 2;
    printf("%i", eh.x);
}
```

Comment: "isn't working" isn't useful.  What's not working?

Comment: Yeah.  For your future questions, it's good to describe the specific problem you are having and also include compilable code (or code that is close to compiling) that reproduces the issue.  The code you provided is missing the declaration of `printf` so that makes it unnecessarily hard for others to reproduce your problem.  See: [mcve].

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C the assignment operator expects an expression but in this expression statement

```
eh = {1, 2};
```

the braced list is not an expression.

The braced list can be used in initialization of an object. For example you could write

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
} eh = { 1, 2 };
```

or

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
} eh = { .x = 1, .y = 2 };
```

Or you could in main assign another object of the structure type using the compound literal like

```
eh = ( struct point ){ 1, 2 };
```

or

```
eh = ( struct point ){ .x = 1, .y = 2 };
```

The compound literal creates an unnamed object of the type `struct point` that is assigned to the object `eh`. One object of a structure type may be assigned to another object of the same structure type.

You could also initialize the object eh with the compound literal

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
} eh = ( struct point ){ .x = 1, .y = 2 };
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 7):

That kind of syntax might work in some other languages, but in C you should write:

```
eh = (struct point){1, 2};
```

The expression on the right hand side is called a *compound literal*.

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main(void) {
    struct point eh = {1, 2};
    printf("%i", eh.x);
}
```

Note that I removed some things around, added the `stdio.h` include and fixed the `main` function type and arguments.